# Nativescript service generation results in call stack error

Tags: service, nativescript, tns

I am currently developing a nativescript application and there were no problems until a particular point from which the generation of a service results in a very long running task and a call stack error at the end.
Here is how I generate a service:

```
tns generate service name=geo-coding
```

I cannot find out why this is happening and also tried to delete the node_modules, hooks and platform folders and reinstalled it with

```
npm install
```

after this I get the same error again:

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>       at t._error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/@nativescript/schematics-executor/dist/index.js:16:1479)
>       at t.error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/@nativescript/schematics-executor/dist/index.js:16:1173)
>       at t._error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/@nativescript/schematics-executor/dist/index.js:16:1479)
>       at t.error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/@nativescript/schematics-executor/dist/index.js:16:1173)
>       at t._error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/@nativescript/schematics-executor/dist/index.js:16:1479)
>       at t.error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/@nativescript/schematics-executor/dist/index.js:16:1173)
>       at t._error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/@nativescript/schematics-executor/dist/index.js:16:1479)
>       at t.error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/@nativescript/schematics-executor/dist/index.js:16:1173)
>       at t._error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/@nativescript/schematics-executor/dist/index.js:16:1479)
>       at t.error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/@nativescript/schematics-executor/dist/index.js:16:1173)
>       at t._error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/@nativescript/schematics-executor/dist/index.js:16:1479)
>       at t.error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/@nativescript/schematics-executor/dist/index.js:16:1173)
>       at e._trySubscribe (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/@nativescript/schematics-executor/dist/index.js:16:4751)
>       at e.subscribe (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/@nativescript/schematics-executor/dist/index.js:16:4427)
>       at e.call (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/@nativescript/schematics-executor/dist/index.js:30:1459)
>       at e.subscribe (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/@nativescript/schematics-executor/dist/index.js:16:4299)

I am very grateful for any help!

Comment: Not sure if this is currently supported. You can check the following thread - https://github.com/sebawita/nativescript-angular-cli/issues/4

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach didn't help me... what do you mean by "not sure if this is currently supported"? The service generation itself should be supported in nativescript, isn't it?

Comment: I have not used it by myself so I am not aware of service generation with nativescript

Comment: So there is no way around generating them manually.. shouldn't be too bad. Thanks!